# I can not see any issues in Sonar Eclipse Plugin after adapting my new rules

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I create new sonar plug-in for checking code quality.
This plugin checks the code quality and creates issues if code violates my rules.

I installed this plugin in sonar/extensions/plugins and restart sonar. 
And then when I analyze source in sonar server side, issues are created in sonar dashboard for violated code. No Problems!

But, If I analyze source using sonar-eclipse-plugin-3.2 in Eclipse,
No issue is created on source issue tab though my plugin is called by sonar-eclipse-plugin-3.2 and source is analyzed. (I checked this through console messages.)

the source has code quality violations and the issues are created in Sonar Server Dashboard. But only on Eclipse Side, no issue is created on Sonar Issues Tab.

What can I do for solving this problem? :(

Please Help me!!!

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse plugin currently only supports Java, C/C++ and Python. If you want the SonarQube Eclipse plugin to support the language you just developped a plugin for, you should update the SonarQube Eclipse plugin. Out of curiosity, what is the language you added support to?

Comment: it's for java, and I solved this problem. Resource key for Java resources should be the package name and not the relative file path in issues.